# PHP preg match all

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

```
$str = <a href="keep.php?casuser=400000018623110" onclick="ajaxLinkSend('globalContainer', 'keep.php?casuser=400000018623110'); return false;" style="color:#ffca3e">
```

My working preg match all:

```
preg_match_all('/\'keep.php\?casuser=(.*) style=\"color:#ffca3e/iU', $result, $matches2);
$matches2[1][0] = 400000018623110'); return false;"
```

But I want only the numbers

No result with:

```
preg_match_all('/\'keep.php\?casuser=(.*)\'\); return false;" style=\"color:#ffca3e/iU', $result, $matches2);
```

Can anyone help me with that? And explain me why its not working?
thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slightly confused by the question - and I'd put this in a comment if I had the rep.

Is this sufficient

```
preg_match_all('/\'keep.php\?casuser=(\d*)/i', $result, $matches2);
```

or is it important that they also have the relevant style? If so try:

```
preg_match_all('/\'keep.php\?casuser=(\d*).*?style=\"color:#ffca3e/i', $result, $matches2);
```

Comment: thx ye style is relevant and thank you very much the second answer is working for me :)

Comment: In terms of why yours don't work: You first one matches all characters between casuser= and [space]style=
The second one matches all character between casuser= and the next single quotation mark ' which I would have expected to return 400000018623110" onclick="ajaxLinkSend(', but either way is incorrect. Glad to help.

Comment: no i start with \' cuz i only want the secound number :) but i still dont understand why my second try wasnt working